# Convert caf file to m4r programmatically on ios4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

Is there a way to convert a .caf file to a .m4r (ringtone) file programmatically on the iPhone? I've tried a bunch of stuff and nothing seems to work. Importing into garageband and then sharing as ringtone works but I want to do it in my app.

Comment: Bump :-) I'll try to investigate this too as I have a similar need.

Comment: Anybody got any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

AVFoundation and its class AVAssetExportSession

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avassetexportsession

To use the above class, you have to create a AVAsset (or one of its inherited classes) and supply that to exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: for instance. I recently found out that even though exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: is supported from iOS 4.0, it seems that you really need iOS 4.1 because exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler: in turn uses the 4.1 exportSessionWithAsset:presetName:

Comment: Oh, you can export sound as AAC (.m4a), but I don't see any problem of renaming the file to .m4r, you could do it at export time or after exporting - I don't think the filename matters to the encoding process.